# Using stackexchange markup in WordPress (plugin?)

Tags: stackoverflow

What plugin/etc lets me use stackexchange markup in WordPress?

I was sure someone would've asked this question, but both of these searches:

```
+"stackexchange markup" 
+"stack markup"
```

returned nothing.

Answer (score 3):

Stackexchange uses the classic [Markdown](http://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/). I think [this plugin](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/markdown-for-wordpress-and-bbpress/) will work for you.

Also the code parts uses [Google Code Prettify](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wp-code-prettify/), which also has a WordPress plugin.